# Transforming long format data to short format by segmenting dates that include redundant observations

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data set that is long format and includes exact date/time measurements of 3 scores on a single test administered between 3 and 5 times per year.

```
    ID  Date                    Fl  Er  Cmp
    1   9/24/2010 11:38         15  2   17
    1   1/11/2011 11:53         39  11  25
    1   1/15/2011 11:36         39  11  39
    1   3/7/2011 11:28          95  58  2
    2   10/4/2010 14:35         35  9   6
    2   1/7/2011 13:11          32  7   8
    2   3/7/2011 13:11          79  42  30
    3   10/12/2011 13:22        17  3   18
    3   1/19/2012 14:14         45  15  36
    3   5/8/2012 11:55          29  6   11
    3   6/8/2012 11:55          74  37  7
    4   9/14/2012 9:15          62  28  18
    4   1/24/2013 9:51          82  45  9
    4   5/21/2013 14:04         135 87  17
    5   9/12/2011 11:30         98  61  18
    5   9/15/2011 13:23         55  22  9
    5   11/15/2011 11:34        98  61  17
    5   1/9/2012 11:32          55  22  17
    5   4/20/2012 11:30         23  4   17
```

I need to transform this data to short format with time bands based on month (i.e. Fall=August-October; Winter=January-February; Spring=March-May). Some bands will include more than one observation per participant, and as such, will need a "spill over" band. An example transformation for the Fl scores below.

```
ID  Fall1Fl     Fall2Fl     Winter1Fl       Winter2Fl       Spring1Fl       Spring2Fl
1   15          NA          39              39              95              NA
2   35          NA          32              NA              79              NA
3   17          NA          45              NA              28              74
4   62          NA          82              NA              135             NA
5   98          55          55              NA              23              NA
```

Notice that dates which are "redundant" (i.e. more than 1 Aug-Oct observation) spill over into Fall2fl column. Dates that occur outside of the desired bands (i.e. November, December, June, July) should be deleted. The final data set should have additional columns that include Fl Er and Cmp.

Any help would be appreciated!

(Link to .csv file with long data http://mentor.coe.uh.edu/Data_Example_Long.csv )

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated what you have tried.  I would use the following strategy:  Add a column to the long df, indicating which  timeband it belongs to. Do any necessary spill-over / shifting calculations before reshaping.  Then use `library(reshape2)` to melt the data into the wide format that you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you are looking for, but doesn't *exactly* match your desired output. I haven't looked at your sample data to see whether the problem lies with your sample desired output or the transformations I've done, but you should be able to follow along with the code to see how the transformations were made.

```
## Convert dates to actual date formats
mydf$Date <- strptime(gsub("/", "-", mydf$Date), format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")

## Factor the months so we can get the "seasons" that you want
Months <- factor(month(mydf$Date), levels=1:12)
levels(Months) <- list(Fall = c(8:10),
                       Winter = c(1:2),
                       Spring = c(3:5),
                       Other = c(6, 7, 11, 12))
mydf$Seasons <- Months

## Drop the "Other" seasons
mydf <- mydf[!mydf$Seasons == "Other", ]

## Add a "Year" column
mydf$Year <- year(mydf$Date)

## Add a "Times" column
mydf$Times <- as.numeric(ave(as.character(mydf$Seasons), 
                             mydf$ID, mydf$Year, FUN = seq_along))

## Load "reshape2" and use `dcast` on just one variable.
##   Repeat for other variables by changing the "value.var"
dcast(mydf, ID ~ Seasons + Times, value.var="Fluency")
#   ID Fall_1 Fall_2 Winter_1 Winter_2 Spring_2 Spring_3
# 1  1     15     NA       39       39       NA       95
# 2  2     35     NA       32       NA       79       NA
# 3  3     17     NA       45       NA       29       NA
# 4  4     62     NA       82       NA      135       NA
# 5  5     98     55       55       NA       23       NA
```